# ansible expect module throwing error Module failure Parse: failed

Tags: ansible

my playbook is like

```
- name: configuring pdf harmony
  expect:
  command: ./install.sh
   responses:
     'This will install pdfharmony on your system. Do you want to continue[y/N]?': y
     'Do you agree with this copyright? [y/N]': y
     'Now you must enter a valid registration number:': XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
  echo: yes
  args:
    chdir: '{{ dest_dir }}/pdfHarmony_20_L26_64'
  become: yes
```

Error:

```
fatal: [10.135.232.213]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "./install.sh", 
"delta": "0:00:30.186764", "end": "2016-08-12 14:02:23.384237", "failed": 
true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"chdir": 
"/usr/local/pdfHarmony_20_L26_64", "command": "./ 
mounted or mapped drive. You may not copy the software to use for ", 
"development, testing or staging purposes.", "", "1.  Restrictions:  You may 
not resell, transfer, rent or lease the Software ", "without the specific 
agreement of Appligent. You may not reverse engineer, ", "\u001b[7m--More--
\u001b[27m"]}
```

I could not understand the cause of this error
when installing manually, 
Here when you pass y to the first prompt, you get a copyright agreement which is more than a page and you will find --More-- at the end of the page and when keep on pressing enter last line of the agreement the second prompt(question appears) like
[when you press y for 1st prompt you see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6iDV.png)
then you press more
[after pressing more at last you see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK9QG.png)
then it asks for reg. keys

Update:
 it is like not listening to my next response after more.. i am not able to understand how this is happening
it is not taking my response for 
'Do you agree with this copyright? [y/N]': y

i have added more and now it looks like

```
- name: configuring pdf harmony
  expect:
  command: ./install.sh
  responses:
  'This will install pdfharmony on your system. Do you want to continue[y/N]?': y
  '--More--': \r
  '(?i)Do you agree with this copyright? [y/N]': y
  'Now you must enter a valid registration number': XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
   echo: yes
   args:
    chdir: '{{ dest_dir }}/pdfHarmony_20_L26_64'
   become: yes
```

But now it fails at next response it doesn't take the next response and i don't know why it fails at:

```
"\u001b[7m--More--\u001b[27m\u0007\u0007", "Updates may be licensed to you 
by Appligent with additional or different terms.", "", "Do you agree with 
this copyright? [y/N] : "]}
```

There is a new error with the module and i can make nothing out of it, ichanghed the play to :

```
- name: configuring stamp pdf batch
  expect:
  command: /bin/bash -c "stty rows 2000,2000; ./install.sh"
  responses:
  'This will install stamppdf on your system. Do you want to continue[y/N]?': y
  #    '--More--': \r
 '(?i)Do you agree with this copyright\? \[y/N\]': y
 'AP_FONT_DIR [/usr/local/fonts]': y
 'Now you must enter a valid registration number': '{{ stamp_pdf_key }}'
 echo: yes
 args:
 chdir: '{{ dest_dir }}/StampPDFBatch_60_L26_64'
 become: yes
```

the error is:

```
fatal: [10.135.232.213]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, 
"invocation": {"module_name": "expect"}, "module_stderr": "", 
"module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File 
\"/tmp/ansible_V_modk/ansible_module_expect.py\", line 230, in <module>\r\n
main()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_V_modk/ansible_module_expect.py\", line 199,
in main\r\n    events=events, cwd=chdir, echo=echo)\r\n  File 
\"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect/__init__.py\", line 225, in 
runu\r\n    env=env, _spawn=spawnu, **kwargs)\r\n  File 
\"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect/__init__.py\", line 246, in 
_run\r\n    index = child.expect(patterns)\r\n  File 
\"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect/__init__.py\", line 1451, in 
expect\r\n    timeout, searchwindowsize)\r\n  File 
\"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect/__init__.py\", line 1466, in 
expect_list\r\n    timeout, searchwindowsize)\r\n  File 
\"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect/__init__.py\", line 1535, in 
expect_loop\r\n    c = self.read_nonblocking(self.maxread, timeout)\r\n  
File \"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect/__init__.py\", line 984, in 
read_nonblocking\r\n    s = self._coerce_read_string(s)\r\n  File 
\"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect/__init__.py\", line 1797, in 
_coerce_read_string\r\n    return self._decoder.decode(s, final=False)\r\n 
 File \"/usr/lib64/python2.6/codecs.py\", line 296, in decode\r\n    
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, 
final)\r\nUnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in 
position 1166: invalid continuation byte\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", 
"parsed": false}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to alter TTY height and avoid 'More'-thing:

```
command: /bin/bash -c "stty rows 2000,2000; ./install.sh"
```

Comment: I tried using it but now i get module failure error, can't understand why came across that error